# SharePoint security overview - where to start?

Tags: sharepoint

I need to read-up on SharePoint security. Can anyone recommend where to start? The areas I need to look into are:

1. Security of remote clients which use SharePoint web services (SOAP or RESTful).
2. Security of data sitting on SharePoint.
3. Authentication of users.
4. User permissions.

At the moment, I'm unsure of where to start or even what to Google. I guess a check-list of things to read up on would great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN and technet are very good resources. Search both for "SharePoint Security" and you will find all kinds of things down different tracks like Developer, ITPro.

Try this for a starting point: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518672

Or just start digging here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776256(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is really just an application built on top of 3 main technologies:

- ASP.net web side
- SQL Server database
- Windows operating system

You should start with a basic understanding of these 3 technologies.

You can then go on to how SharePoint handles security within SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the many useful articles on Microsoft TechNet, you should take a look at the SharePoint blog at TITUS.  I don't mean this reply to be as self-serving as it sounds, but the TITUS blog at http://www.titus.com/blog is focussed on SharePoint security.  There are a number of (non-product related) articles and papers there that might be helpful, which  educate on SharePoint security, mostly from a user permissioning, authentication and authorization perspective.  As well, check out the article titled "Effectively Managing Permissions in Microsoft SharePoint 2010" (written by me) at the DIWUG eMagazine site: http://www.diwug.nl/e-magazines/Pages/default.aspx. Again, its focussed on permission management, especially in large libraries and lists in SharePoint (impact on performance, etc).  Hope this helps.
-Antonio